# Higher push-forward of structure sheaf of partial resolution of Affine Cones associated to ample line bundles?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This construction taken from J. Kollar's book *Singularities of MMP*. We just consider varieties over $\mathbb{C}$:

> **[Def]** Let $X$ be a projective variety with a line bundle $\scr{L}$, we define
> $$
> \mathsf{AC}(X,\mathscr{L}):=\mathrm{Spec}\bigoplus_{m\geq0}H^0(X,\mathscr{L}^{\otimes m}).
> $$
>
> Also we consider $\mathsf{BAC}(X,\mathscr{L}):=\underline{\mathrm{Spec}}_X \bigoplus_{m\geq0}\mathscr{L}^{\otimes m}$, then there is a natural morphism
> $$
> p:\mathsf{BAC}(X,\mathscr{L}):=\underline{\mathrm{Spec}}_X \bigoplus_{m\geq0}\mathscr{L}^{\otimes m}\to\mathsf{AC}(X,\mathscr{L})=\mathrm{Spec}\bigoplus_{m\geq0}H^0(X,\mathscr{L}^{\otimes m})
> $$
> by the definition.
> When $\scr{L}$ is ample, $p$ is a blowing up of vertex. So in this case $p$ is a partial resolution.

Here is my question:

> **[Q]** Let $X$ be a projective variety with an ample line bundle $\scr{L}$. Consider again $$
> p:\mathsf{BAC}(X,\mathscr{L}):=\underline{\mathrm{Spec}}_X \bigoplus_{m\geq0}\mathscr{L}^{\otimes m}\to\mathsf{AC}(X,\mathscr{L})=\mathrm{Spec}\bigoplus_{m\geq0}H^0(X,\mathscr{L}^{\otimes m})
> $$
> which is a birational morphism contract $E$ by [Q1]. Why we have:
> $$\mathbf{R}^ip_*\mathscr{O}_{\mathsf{BAC}(X,\mathscr{L})}\cong\bigoplus_{m\geq0}H^i(X,\mathscr{L}^{\otimes m}).$$

In the book, they argued as follows:

Let $\mathscr{I}$ be the ideal sheaf of $E$, then we have
$$\mathscr{O}_{\mathsf{BAC}}/\mathscr{I}^m=\mathscr{O}_X\oplus\mathscr{L}\oplus\cdots\oplus\mathscr{L}^{\otimes m-1}.$$
The the results follows from formal function theorem.

But by formal function theorem we have
$$(\mathbf{R}^ip_*\mathscr{O}_{\mathsf{BAC}(X,\mathscr{L})})_y^{\wedge}\cong H^i(X,\varprojlim_m(\mathscr{O}_X\oplus\mathscr{L}\oplus\cdots\oplus\mathscr{L}^{\otimes m-1}))$$
where $p(E)=\{y\}$.
But I don't know how to drop the completion?

---

Thank you for your any help!

Comment: This is really quite close to your [previously deleted question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4885339/about-affine-cones-associated-to-ample-line-bundles-and-some-calculations). In the future, it's better to edit your post instead of deleting and re-asking.

Comment: @KReiser I'm sorry